# Empty IQueryable that implements IAsyncEnumerable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, iqueryable

I am looking for an empty `IQueryable<T>` that implements `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`. My current code does not work because empty `Enumerable` does not implement `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`. Thanks for any help or hint.

I have the following design:

```
var result = Enumerable.Empty<Foo>().AsQueryable();  // Not working!

if (condition1)
{
    IQueryable<Foo> part1 = ....;

    result = result.Concat(part1);
}

if (condition2)
{
    IQueryable<Foo> part2 = ....;

    result = result.Concat(part2);
}

return await result.ToListAsync();
```

Error message:

```
The source IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncEnumerable<Foo>. Only sources that implement IAsyncEnumerable can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.AsAsyncEnumerable[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Comment: Just curious, why do you need this?

Comment: @MichaelRandall The `....` I have represented querying from `DbSet`. The result is `IQueryable<Foo>`. I am trying to join the two `IQueryable<Foo>` and await on `ToListAsync()`. `result` needs to implement `IAsyncEnumerable<Foo>` for everything to work out. I think

Comment: Maybe this post can give you some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59071994/how-do-you-mock-and-iasyncenumerable

Comment: @AmirPopovich I understand but I wish there was a way not bring moq into the project.

Comment: @AmirPopovich I added the error message I am getting

Comment: @Node.JS - I'm not near a computer, so I can't really help you now. I've seen some people talking about an `ToAsyncEnumerable` extension method that may help you..

Comment: Have a look at `System.Linq.Async` package

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the nuget package `System.Linq.Async` to get the `ToAsyncEnumerable()` method:

```
private static async Task<List<Foo>> GetList()
{
    var result = Enumerable.Empty<Foo>().AsQueryable();

    if (true)
    {
        IQueryable<Foo> part1 = new List<Foo> { new Foo() }.AsQueryable();
        result = result.Concat(part1);
    }

    if (true)
    {
        IQueryable<Foo> part2 = new List<Foo> { new Foo(), new Foo() }.AsQueryable();
        result = result.Concat(part2);
    }

    return await result.ToAsyncEnumerable().ToListAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an empty IAsyncEnumerable as it is described in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59443429/create-empty-iasyncenumerable).

But if I don't think it is an ideal option since it requires referencing an additional package or implementing  AsyncEnumerable.Empty on your own.

Alternatively, you could change your code in a way that does not require an "empty" container for your expressions.

For example:

```
var expressions = new List<IQueryable<Foo>>();

if (condition1)
{
    IQueryable<Foo> part1 = ....;

    expressions.Add(part1);
}

if (condition2)
{
    IQueryable<Foo> part2 = ....;

    expressions.Add(part2);
}

var result = expressions.Aggregate((acc, i) => acc.Concat(i));

return await result.ToListAsync();
```