# Convert IQueryable to IAsyncQueryable

Tags: c#, .net, database, linq, iqueryable

My main codebase operate `IAsyncQueryable`, but I have obsolete parts of code / consumed API which has no ability to provide `IAsyncQueryable`, however provides `IQueryable`. What I miss is `IAsyncqueryable ToAsyncQueryable(this IQueryable queryable)` method to convert it (yes, it would be sub-optimal, that's okay until no conversion to `IEnumerable`).

Is any standard approach to deal with it or possibly someone has implementation of such method (I did not find)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please share with us your simplified code and indicate where did you stuck.

Comment: The first answer in this question should be working for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60274758/empty-iqueryable-that-implements-iasyncenumerable

Comment: @volley unfortunately not, you are confusing `IAsyncEnumerable` and `IAsyncQueryable`

Comment: What is the point to operate with IAsyncQueryable? As I know each LINQ Provider has it's own methods to execute async calls.

Comment: `IAsyncQueryable` is more efficient in highly concurrable environment because it does not block thread until fully completed, also you can enumerate result without keeping whole query result in memory. Yes, `IAsyncQueryable` behavior depends on backed implementation (which we have for our primary sources), but third-party provider's like MongoDB.Driver for example implements only `IQueryable`